# Editor Placeholder results in failed builds

Tags: c#, xamarin, editor, placeholder

I'm currently despairing because of a simple Editor in Xamarin.
No matter in what program I use it (if it's HelloWorld or my main project) I just can't set any Placeholder without my program to fail in the build progress.
I spent over 2 hours to find the source of this error but I am still too blind. The error messages are:

> Position 16:96. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Placeholder', or mismatching type between value and property.
>
> Dependent project TableDotGroup.csproj failed to build, using old version.

Neither

```
myEditor.Placeholder = "Please work";
```

nor in the XAML file, aswell as

```
if(myEditor.Text == null)
        {
        myEditor.Placeholder = "Please work";
```

are working. All of my Nuget Packages but the Xamarin.Android.Support ones are up to date. Could it be the Nuget Packages?

**EDIT**

Here is my XAML code:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="editors"  >

            <Label Text="Jungs:" FontSize="Medium"/>
            <Editor x:Name="namesBoys" HeightRequest="150" Completed="NamesBoys_Completed" />
```

and xaml.cs:

```
namesBoys.Placeholder = "Please work";
```

Comment: which version of Xamarin Forms are you using?

Comment: the latest stable one: 3.4.0.1008975 @Jason

Comment: are you sure that all your projects are using the same version?  The Editor placeholder was introduced in 3.2.0

Comment: also, try cleaning all your obj & bin folders in your projects and rebuilding your solution

Comment: I cleaned everything and the versions are matching. New error: 'Editor' does not contain a definition for 'Placeholder' and no extension method 'Placeholder' accepting a first argument of type 'Editor' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) @Jason

Comment: my best guess is that you have a reference to an old version of Forms somewhere. You might try checking your csproj files and packages.config files to be sure they are not pointing to an old version

Comment: do you have the [XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOption.Compile)] in your page? you could try to remove it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that my build itself doesn't fail. Only when I try to debug, the build fails. So the App itself works after distribution, so does the Placeholder. The only problem is, that it doesn't work with the debugger.
Thank all of you